# After updating from Android studio 3.2.1 to 3.3.1, I'm unable to see/change build variants, it is showing 5 hyphens

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.3

I was able to change build variants to devDebug, devRelease,  playStoreDebug, playStoreRelease in Android Studio v3.2.1 and after updating to v3.3.1 I'm unable to change the build variant refer image [Image_In_Android_studio_3.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmPwY.png).

I tried below steps before posting the issue here:-
1. Clean project/rebuild/invalidate Caches and Restart the project
2. Reclone the repository(as it din't work with the existing).

- Have updated - **"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'"** root gradle file and **"distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip"** in gradle-wrapper.properties

build.gradle version 1

```
signingConfigs {
release {
    storeFile file("$project.rootDir/xyz-keystore-release.jks")
    storePassword “xyzzy”
    keyAlias "xyzzy"
    keyPassword "xyzzy"
}}

buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    shrinkResources false
    debuggable true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}}

productFlavors {
playStore {
    applicationId myApplicationId
    manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: true]
}

dev {
    applicationId myApplicationId + ".dev"
    manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false]
}}
```

build.gradle version 2

```
signingConfigs {
release {
    storeFile file("$project.rootDir/xyz-keystore-release.jks")
    storePassword “xyzzy”
    keyAlias "xyzzy"
    keyPassword "xyzzy"
}

debug {
    storeFile file("$project.rootDir/xyz-debug.keystore")
    storePassword "xyzzy"
    keyAlias "xyzzy"
    keyPassword "xyzzy"
}}

buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    shrinkResources false
    debuggable true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
debug {
    minifyEnabled false
    shrinkResources false
    debuggable true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}}

productFlavors {
playStore {
    applicationId myApplicationId
    manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: true]
}

dev {
    applicationId myApplicationId + ".dev"
    manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false]
}}
```

With "build.gradle version 1" in Android studio v3.2.1, I was able to change build variants, after updating to Android studio v3.3.1, I'm unable to.

Comment: What about gradle file can you post it? We need to see buildTypes there

Comment: Click on your module and add/edit your build variant or manually add your variant inside gradle file.

Comment: I have updated the post with build.gradle info - @AssetBekbossynov

Comment: try to add to debug and release version `debuggable true`

Comment: adding `debuggable true` didn't work.